# Coq - adding choice function to context

Tags: math, coq, proof

Suppose I am inside a Coq proof, and the current context includes a hypothesis of the form

```
H : forall a : A, P a -> exists b : B, Q a b
```

where

```
A B:Type
P : A -> Prop
Q : A -> B -> Prop
```

Then, I would like to add two new terms to the context:

```
f : A -> B
H' : forall a : A, P a -> Q a (f a)
```

How can I do this? I am happy to add nonconstructive axioms to achieve this.

Comment: This is different from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66825979/coq-function-choosing-witnesses-for-a-forall-exists-statement) as it is specifically about how to add these terms to the context *inside* a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this generality, this is not possible. Look at the following:

```
Definition A : Type := True.
Definition B : Type := False.
Definition P : A -> Prop := (fun a : A => False).
Definition Q : A -> B -> Prop := (fun (a : A) (b : B) => True).

Example H_is_trivial: forall a : A, P a -> exists b : B, Q a b.
Proof.
  intros a HP.
  destruct HP.
Qed.

Example f_cannot_exist: (exists f : A -> B, forall a : A, P a -> Q a (f a)) -> False.
Proof.
  intros.
  destruct H as [f H].
  apply f.
  exact I.
Qed.
```

So there exist assignments for A, B, P and Q in which your H holds, but one can prove that your f cannot exist.

For the refined problem, you can define a simga type {a | P a} und prove with the axiom of choice:

```
Require Import ClassicalChoice.

Section Test.
Variable A B : Type.
Variable P : A -> Prop.
Variable Q : A -> B -> Prop.
Variable H : forall a : A, P a -> exists b : B, Q a b.

Definition AP := { a : A | P a }.
Definition QAP (a : AP) (b : B) := Q (proj1_sig a) b.

Lemma f_exists: exists f : AP -> B, (forall ap : AP, QAP ap (f ap)).
  apply choice.
  intros ap.
  specialize (H (proj1_sig ap) (proj2_sig ap)).
  destruct H as [b HQ].
  exists b. exact HQ.
Qed.
```

It shouldn't be hard to take the sigma type apart again and get to your immediate question, but the sigma type might anyway be more convenient.

Comment: Good catch. I suppose instead that I want an `f` which takes pairs `(a : A, p : P a)` to elements of `B`? And then the hypothesis `H' : forall (a : A)(p : P a), Q a (f a p)`.